# Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I edited my config/secrets.yml file but I'm still getting the same error:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["random key"] %>

test:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["random key"] %>

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["random key"] %>
```

My config/devise.rb file looks like this:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "no-reply@myapp.com"
  config.secret_key = ENV["random key"]
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.password_length = 8..128
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

Comment: "random key" is not a valid environment variable. You could try "RANDOM_KEY". Also have you set up your environment variables on your machine?

Comment: @Ropeney What I meant by "random key" is the key I obtained by running "rake secret" on the terminal. So "random key" represents something like this: "0639e5fce51aef9e3e552d60eaf951bf01c0fd1ea14d4173a4bdc56c7c71fc63cacf78a9c81d3f5a276bb9e567b0cec6d80ed22593ab480735b6aed08067e800".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the random key in an environment file. I suggest using something like https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv for managing them.

In the `.env` file you put

```
SECRET_KEY=0639e5fce51aef9e3e552d60eaf951bf01c0fd1ea14d4173a4bdc56c7c71fc63cacf78a9c81d3f5‌​a276bb9e567b0cec6d80ed22593ab480735b6aed08067e800
```

Then in your files above you do

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY'] %>
```